# Rails: ZIP file shown in browser instead of being downloaded

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

My controller sends a ZIP file:

```
def index
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html  { render :text => open("tmp/test1.zip", "rb").read }
  end
end
```

**PROBLEM:** the ZIP is received as text shown in the browser.
I would like it to come as a download.

Note: I wrote `format.html` because when I write `format.zip` I get `uninitialized constant Mime::ZIP`. That is probably part of the problem.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can register your own mime type:

```
Mime::Type.register "application/zip", :zip

def index
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html  { ... } #do whatever you need for html
    format.csv  { ... } #do whatever you need for csv
    format.zip  { send_file 'your_file.zip' }
  end
end
```

have a look here:

http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2006/12/19/using-custom-mime-types

Comment: Great! Adding this single `Mime::Type.register "application/zip", :zip` line solves the problem! Accepting this answer even though older answers have been upvoted more.

Answer (score 4):

You should probably use [ActionController::DataStreaming#send_file](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/DataStreaming.html#method-i-send_file) Take a look here:

> http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/DataStreaming.html#method-i-send_file

Answer (score 2):

You can skip the `respond_to` stuff and manually set the content type:

```
def index
  render :file => '/full/path/to/tmp/test1.zip', :content_type => 'application/zip', :status => :ok
end
```

See the [Layouts and Rendering in Rails](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html) guide for more information.

If you want to support `.csv` as well, then you could try looking at the `params[:format]`:

```
def index
  if params[:format] == 'zip'
    # send back the zip as above.
  elsif params[:format] == 'csv'
    # send back the CSV
  else
    # ...
  end
end
```

And have a look at [`send_file`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/DataStreaming.html#method-i-send_file) as Marian Theisen suggests.

Comment: Actually I also have a `format.csv` line (which works fine), I removed it as I thought it was not relevant for the question.

Comment: @Nicolas: You can handle the format manually as well, I've added an update for that.

Answer (score 0):

*a simple solution for the user to download a file located in the application*

```
def index
   send_data File.read('/full/path/to/tmp/test1.zip'), filename: "test1.zip"
end
```

`send_data` will read your file located here `/full/path/to/tmp/test1.zip` and then send it as a response as a file

and your user download a file with filename `test1.zip`

Comment: Code only answers are discouraged. Please add some explanation as to how this solves the problem, or how this differs from the existing answers. [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/23987466)